# Custom Button and Link can't use VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-button

I am creating a new custom button or link, and when i try to use a Visualforce page my content dropdown list is empty. How do i get a VF page to trigger on a custom button or link.

Comment: Add some code to make this clear?

Answer (score 7):

You need to ensure your **Visualforce** page uses a [Standard Controller](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Building_Visualforce_Pages_Using_the_Standard_Controller) for your object.

For **Detail Page** custom buttons...

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
```

For **List View** custom buttons...

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts">
```

Then Salesforce will display your pages in the drop down list.

You can read a more detailed walk through and some security considerations [here](http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/07/16/how-to-call-apex-code-from-a-custom-button/).

Comment: Damnit you beat me to my complete answer with List buttons and detail buttons, +1 all mighty Andrew

Comment: Ha sorry dude, bit of a hot topic for me a few blog posts back this one, quite a bit to it once you get into the detail of it...